# aws api-gateway forward request to lambda function stuck

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I'm kinda new to aws. I have been trying to create a simple registration form client. created a dynamodb and a lambda function that writes to that dynamodb here is the code. The matter is that the request doesn't even reach the lambda by the logs, it says

```
Execution log for request test-request
Sun Aug 20 14:33:44 UTC 2017 : Starting execution for request: test-invoke-request
Sun Aug 20 14:33:44 UTC 2017 : HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /mosesdb
Sun Aug 20 14:33:44 UTC 2017 : Method request path: {}
Sun Aug 20 14:33:44 UTC 2017 : Method request query string: {}
Sun Aug 20 14:33:44 UTC 2017 : Method request headers: {}
Sun Aug 20 14:33:44 UTC 2017 : Method request body before transformations: {
    "objectId": "123456789",
    "objectFullName": "asdkjh",
    "objectPhone": "1234567",
    "objectEmail": "@."
}
Sun Aug 20 14:33:44 UTC 2017 : Execution failed due to configuration error: API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role
Sun Aug 20 14:33:44 UTC 2017 : Method completed with status: 500
```

I think the important part here is the

```
Sun Aug 20 14:33:44 UTC 2017 : Execution failed due to configuration error: API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role
```

I don't understand if I configured the API to 
Authorization None
API Key Not required
then why and where can i configure the role? I was looking everywhere and all the information on this relates to when you authenticate using IAM authentication, do I have to use a role on the client?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have added correct arn of lambda function in API gateway. Also set proper role to run lambda function. Lambda basic execution role will be enough to get basic privileges. You can check below video,

https://youtu.be/0HwO14p9cjk